# Excel / DAX / Power Query: How to filter table to find records that fill within a 24 hour window from two dates

Tags: sql, excel, date, dax, powerquery

got my head stumped with this one. Not even sure if its possible.

I have 2 dates column: "Date_of_Call" and "Error_Open_Time"

I want to filter this report to only show records where Error_Open_Time falls within a 24 hour window from Date_of_Call time.

Example:

If Error_Open_Time = '11/6/2016 1:17:00 PM' and Date_of_Call = '11/6/2016 12:00:00 AM', then this record SHOULD show up in the filter since Error_Open_Time falls within the 24 hour window.

If Error_Open_Time = '12/11/2016 12:35:00 AM' and Date_of_Call = '12/10/2016 12:00:00 AM', then this record SHOULD NOT show up in the filter since Error_Open_Time DOES NOT fall within the 24 hour window.

Also, if Error_Open_Time date is before Date_of_Call date then it should be filtered out since it is not necessary.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Does Date_of _Call column contain time information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract dates together in Power Query, which will give you a duration. If the `Error_Open_Time` and `Date_of_Call` columns are `Date` or `DateTime` types, then this should do the trick:

1. Add a custom column with the formula `[Error_Open_Time] - [Date_of_Call]`
2. Filter the custom column to be between a 24-hour period. You can do "is greater than or equal to" `-1.00:00:00` and "is less than or equal to" `1.00:00:00` (between 1 day).
3. Remove the custom column

The steps should look like this:

`#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [Error_Open_Time] - [Date_of_Call]),
 #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Custom] >= #duration(-1, 0, 0, 0) and [Custom] <= #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),
 #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom"})`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column in your table to determine the records to filter.

```
=
IF (
    'Table'[Date_of_Call]
        = DATE ( YEAR ( 'Table'[Error_Open_Time] ), MONTH ( 'Table'[Error_Open_Time] ), DAY ( 'Table'[Error_Open_Time] ) ),
    1,
    0
)
```

Then in your report add a filter that uses only the values equal to 1 in the calculated column.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Did not think this method would work but surprisingly it did! Got the same results as using  Alejandro's method. I think it worked because the Date_of_Call column dates are all using 12:00:00AM as timestamp. If the timestamps were different then I dont think this method work.

Comment: @NickMomin, yes because of that I asked you in a comment if Date_of_Call contains time information. After I figured you used 12:00:00 so thought it doesn't.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Just thought I would include why / when it would not work if someone in a similar situation was looking for a solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For PowerQuery, I would do it in a single line, there is no need to add columns:

```
FilterRecords = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Error_Open_Time] > [Date_of_Call]) and ([Date_of_Call] + #duration(1,0,0,0) >= [Error_Open_Time]))
```

Also this variant is possible:

```
FilterRecords = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Error_Open_Time] > [Date_of_Call]) and (Date.AddDays([Date_of_Call], 1) >= [Error_Open_Time]))
```

If you need SQL, then use

```
SELECT [Date_of_Call], [Error_Open_Time]
FROM Table
WHERE [Error_Open_Time] > [Date_of_Call] 
      AND 
      (DateAdd(day, 1, [Date_of_Call]) >= [Error_Open_Time])
```